# Java - Assistance with understanding codility code

Tags: java

For the PermCheck codility test, I coded one solution (please see below) but it only really solved the example given in the codility test because there are only a few values in the array and small values. I also added code below which scored 100%, which is code I found on the internet. That code looks very different from mine and I couldn't work out how he/she was able to get the answer. Could someone please explain the code step by step and how it results in the answer please.

**Codility Test:**

**PermCheck**

Check whether array A is a permutation.

A non-empty zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given.

A permutation is a sequence containing each element from 1 to N once, and only once.

For example, array `A` such that:

```
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 2
```

is a permutation, but array `A` such that:

```
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 3
```

is not a permutation, because value 2 is missing.

The goal is to check whether array `A` is a permutation.

Write a function:

```
class Solution {
    public int solution(int[] A);
}
```

that, given a zero-indexed array `A`, `returns 1` if array `A` is a permutation and `0` if it is not.

For example, given array A such that:

```
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 3
A[3] = 2
```

the function should return 1.

Given array A such that:

```
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 3
```

the function should return 0.

Assume that:

- N is an integer within the range [1..100'000];
- Each element of array A is an integer within the range [1..1'000'000'000].

**Complexity:**

- Expected worst-case time complexity is O(N)
- Expected worst-case space complexity is O(N), beyond input storage (not counting the storage required for input arguments).
- Elements of input arrays can be modified.

**100% Score Solution (found from internet):**

```
public static final int NOT_PERMUTATION = 0;
public static final int PERMUTATION = 1;
// (4,1,3,2) = 1
// (4,1,3) = 0
// (1) = 1
// () = 1
// (2) = 0
public int PermSolution(int[] A) {
    // write your code in Java SE 8
    int[] mark = new int[A.length + 1];
    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; ++i) {
        int value = A[i];
        if(value >= mark.length) {
            return NOT_PERMUTATION;
        }
        if(mark[value] == 0) {
            mark[value]=1;
            ++counter;
        } else {
            return NOT_PERMUTATION;
        }
    }

    return counter == A.length ? PERMUTATION : NOT_PERMUTATION;
}
```

**My Solution:**

```
public int PermSolution(int[] A)
{
    int perm = 1;

    Arrays.sort(A);

    if (A[0] != 1) return 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
        if (A[i] + 1 == A[i + 1])
        {
            return perm;
        }

        if (A[i] + 1 != A[i + 1])
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return perm;

}
```

Comment: Hint : what is the complexity of `Arrays.sort(A)` ?

Comment: This isn't coursework/homework. This is something I'm doing in my own time. I don't understand what the point is of stackoverflow if it's not used to get help from other coders? The task is simple unless the code is too difficult for others to understand too?

Comment: @user2886115 don't worry about one rude comment, flag it if you feel. Actually your question is well formed, but not clear. *Is your sollution working??*, if not... where are you stuck?, if yes, you must place this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Codility isn't just for students. Source: I've been given codility tests for job interviews. OP appears to be asking for optimisation tips because his code only works on smaller samples.

Comment: Jordi Castilla, my solution works but scored very low because it only works for a few conditions such as the one given in the example test but it won't work when its complex e.g. bigger array with larger numbers, which is just one example.

Comment: Dan Pantry, thank you, you understood my question.

Comment: I wasn't trying to be rude. Just thought it was a typical assignment. Sorry if it sounded hurtful.

Comment: @JordiCastilla Note that asking for code explanation is off-topic at Code Review. We assume the OP wrote it himself and knows why he wrote it. That's very important.

Comment: @Mast, I know and I cleary said: *if your code is working, you must place this question at http://codereview.stackexchange.com .* I cannot understand totally question and problems OP is having, so, i proposed 2 ways to act...

Comment: Robin Dorbell, no worries, apology accepted :D

Comment: This exact question was asked before in exactly similar manner, although it was missing the "my code" part.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking to explain code found on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using  `Arrays.sort()` is kind of original, that's not how I would have done it though.

To comment your code, it's probably isn't working because of this :  `return perm;`

Let's say you have this Array which is not a permutation:

```
A[0] = 4
A[1] = 1
A[2] = 2
```

One you execute `Arrays.sort(A)`, you'll have this :

```
A[0] = 1
A[1] = 2
A[2] = 4
```

Now let's execute your code :

```
if (A[0] != 1) return 0;
```

`A[0]` is indeed equal to `1` 
Next, for `i==0` we have :

```
  if (A[i] + 1 == A[i + 1])
    {
        return perm;
    }
```

`A[i] + 1` is equal `2` and `A[i+1]` is also equal to `2`
the condition being `true`, you execute a `return perm;` and thus, you end your execution with a `return 1`.

Actually, as long as your array contains `1` and `2`, this function will always `return 1`

For it to work, you'll have to check all of the array before actually returning a value.

This should work :

```
public int PermSolution(int[] A)
{

int perm = 1;
Arrays.sort(A);

if (A[0] != 1) return 0;

for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
{
       if (A[i] + 1 != A[i + 1])
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

return perm;

}
```

To optimize it even further, this should work as well :

```
public int PermSolution(int[] A)
    {

    Arrays.sort(A);

    for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++)
    {
           if (A[i] != i+1)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    return 1;

    }
```

Comment: I think this is not a very constructive answer. The idea behind these kinds of tests are to test **you**. If you ask for help somewhere else, it's no longer you who are doing the test. Not to mention that codility tests are indeed used in interviews, and I'm always hesitant to give out (technical) interview advice.

Comment: Thank you Mel, the last one scored 100% and it's very simple.

Comment: @user2886115 So you didn't really want to learn, you just wanted someone to write you the solution?

Comment: Kayaman, optimizing the code, is not something you find in the internet,  the aim was not to 'give' the answer, but to explain why the given answer isn't good enough. It is not something that can be figured out on its own. How, then, are we supposed to learn ?

Comment: I'm not complaining about your explaining. I'm complaining about you writing code. You don't learn much when someone gives you out the solutions right away. That's why schools give out homework instead of answer sheets.

Comment: Point taken, there is some truth to that

Comment: Kayaman, you only understand one mode of learning. I'm going through his code on eclipse as we speak and I'm trying to understand it step by step - and seeing where I went wrong. I've already been through quite a few codility tests before this one which I've done fine on and some that I didn't I worked out eventually. I was just stuck on this one. Sometimes seeing code that others have done and going through it, helps me to understand where I went wrong and how to better it next time. I'm going to use the understanding I get from this one on future tests to better optimise it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't we avoid Arrays.sort(A)  in order to gain the computation efficiency by below:

```
public static int PermSolution(int[] A)
{
    int len=A.length;
    if(len==1)
        return A[0]==1 ? 1 : 0;

    BitSet set=new BitSet(len+2);

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if(A[i]>len || set.get(A[i]))
            return 0;

        set.set(A[i]);
    }
    return set.nextClearBit(1)==(len+1) ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some solution that I have developed. Not sure about constraints, if someone can help to test it against them. Thanks people!

```
private static int solution(int[] arr) {

        int perm=1;
        boolean b=false;
        Arrays.sort(arr);
        int i=0;
        while (i<=arr.length) {
            if(i < arr.length-2)
                b = arr[i+1]-1 == (arr[i]);
            if(b) {
                System.out.println("if " + i);
                i++;
                perm=1;
            }else {
                System.out.println("else " + i);
                perm = 0;
                break;
            }
        }   
        return perm;
    }
```